# Assign values to column based on same values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Market | Status | Team | Member |
-------|--------|------|--------|
Chicago|   1    |  ENG |  None  |
Chicago|   1    |  ENG |  None  |
SF Bay |   3    |  ENG |  Julia |
```

And a dictionary of users and their emails:

```
TeamMembers = {
    "Julia": "julia@email.com", "Tyler": "tyler@email.com", "Kyle": "kyle@email.com"
}
```

In my DataFrame I want to randomly assign a Member if there is none, but if the Market value is the same, then the Member needs to also be the same.

I want to use

```
name, email = random.choice(list(TeamMembers.items()))
```

to get the specific names and email addresses but I'm not sure how to manipulate the DataFrame based on the Market being the same value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html), also generate only `name`s by change `item`s to `key`s:

```
df['Member'] = (df.groupby('Market')['Member']
                  .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(random.choice(list(TeamMembers.keys())))))
print (df)
    Market  Status Team Member
0  Chicago       1  ENG   Kyle
1  Chicago       1  ENG   Kyle
2   SF Bay       3  ENG  Julia
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution. The benefit of this one is that if Chicago has been mapped once to a Member, other instances will get mapped to the same Member, even if currently `None`.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame([['Chicago', 1, 'ENG', None],
                   ['Chicago', 1, 'ENG', None],
                   ['SF Bay', 3, 'ENG', 'Julia'],
                   ['SF Bay', 2, 'ENG', None],
                   ['NY', 1, 'ENG', None],
                   ['NY', 2, 'ENG', None]],
                  columns=['Market', 'Status', 'Team', 'Member'])

TeamMembers = {"Julia": "julia@email.com", "Tyler": "tyler@email.com", "Kyle": "kyle@email.com"}

existing_map = df.dropna(subset=['Member']).set_index('Market')['Member'].to_dict()
unmapped = list(set(df.loc[pd.isnull(df['Member']), 'Market']) - set(existing_map))

MemberChoices = list(TeamMembers.keys())
random.shuffle(unmapped)
random.shuffle(MemberChoices)

additional_map = {k: MemberChoices[i % len(MemberChoices)] for i, k in enumerate(unmapped)}

new_map = {**existing_map, **additional_map}

df['Member'] = df['Member'].fillna(df['Market'].map(new_map))

#     Market  Status Team Member
# 0  Chicago       1  ENG  Tyler
# 1  Chicago       1  ENG  Tyler
# 2   SF Bay       3  ENG  Julia
# 3   SF Bay       2  ENG  Julia
# 4       NY       1  ENG   Kyle
# 5       NY       2  ENG   Kyle
```

Comment: That's an interesting take -- I like it! Do you know of a way to ensure further randomness in assignments? I.e. if `Julia` has been assigned, she won't get assigned to another market until the rest of the list of team members has been sorted through? The list is rather large and I'm trying to ensure uniformity in assigning markets so that it's technically 'random', but ensuring no one 'randomly' gets assigned 20 and another person gets assigned 1.

Comment: @ATCH_torn. sure, see updated solution. The modulo operator does just this. also I've shuffled up the unmapped Markets and members to avoid any initial bias.

Answer (score 0):

Without `groupby`

```
k=df.Market.unique().tolist()
list(TeamMembers.keys())
Out[31]: ['Julia', 'Tyler', 'Kyle']

d=dict(zip(k,random.sample(set(list(TeamMembers.keys())), 2)))
df.Member=df.Member.fillna(df.Market.map(d))
```